# Understanding the Syntax of Gps_traits_2::Polygons_with_holes_2 in CGAL and Additional Related Questions

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

Good day,

I am currently in the learning process of CGAL while being relatively new to C++. For my current project I need to use Minkowski sums and then do additional operations on the boundary of it.

However, before I do these additional operations I need to get a better understanding of the output of `offset_polygon_2()`, the exact Minkowski offset computation.

## Question 1: What is the Syntax of the output for `.outer_boundary`?

From what I understand so far, it outputs a list of a conic circles defined [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__conic__traits__2.html). I would also imagine you would need some kind of arc-angle range for each of these concic circles and origin point, correct? An example of the output goes something like this:

```
89 {-1*x^2 + -1*y^2 + 0*xy + 1400*x + 0*y + -489975} : (705,0) --ccw--> (700,5) {0*x^2 + 0*y^2 + 0*xy + 0*x + 0*y + 0} : (700,5) --l--> (699.97,5)...
```

## Question 2: How do you use CGAL::draw() for the above?

I have the following code, but I am unsure of what else needs to be done before it can be drawn.

```
Offset_polygon_with_holes_2 offset = CGAL::offset_polygon_2(P, 5, traits);
    double secs = timer.time();
    std::cout << "The offset polygon has " << offset.outer_boundary().size()
                << " vertices, " << offset.number_of_holes() << " holes."
                << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Offset computation took " << secs << " seconds." << std::endl;
```

## Question 3: What other operations can be done on the "offset"?

So in the example code for Minkowski sums (also see above) `offset.outer_boundary()` is done, is there a list of other operations that can be done? Note: I do not think "operations" is the correct term here, please correct me.

I think that is all I have for now, thanks!

Comment: 1. Q 1 is unclear. Any boundary in this context is a sequence of line segments and circular arcs. These curves are handled by the Arr_conic_traits_2 class template. 2. The CGAL::draw() function is rather new. I don't know whether it is possible to draw such curves; try it. Construct a 2D arrangement of conic arcs and draw it; see the examples in the "2D Arrangement"" package. Alternatively, obtain the underlying arrangement of the general polygon you get; see the arrangement() call in the General_polygon_set_2 class template. 3. Compile and run the demo of the "2D Arrangement" package.

Comment: @EfiFogel Thanks for the response. To clarify question 1: I am wondering what the syntax is for the output of the method `outer_boundary` for the output of `offset_polygon_2()`. When I "print" this output to a file, I get `89 {CONIC EQUATION}: (x,y) --ccw-->(x',y')...` and I was wondering what the (x,y), (x'y'), --ccw-->, --l--> represent. As for Question 2, I will play more with `draw()`, but besides that, are there other methods for displaying these 2D arrangements or would I just be better off converting the conics to a set of vertices? 3. I will take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: ccw---counterclockwise, cw---clockwise, l---linear, (x,y)---source point, (x'y')---target point. See Arrangement_2/include/CGAL/Arr_geometry_traits/Conic_x_monotone_arc_2.h and look for the exporter (<<) operator. Also read the manual of Arr_conic_traits_2 (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__conic__traits__2.html)